# qt setmodal does not work

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to set this QT UI to be "modal less", I tried setModal(false), but unfortunately it does not work. meanings: it compiles and runs but I still cannot have the child UI and parent to work in parallel. I am using QT 4.8. On Visual Studio 2010. Here is my code:

```
realtimedlg::realtimedlg(QWidget *parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    parentWnd = parent;
    init();
    timer1.start(100, this); 
    this->setModal(false); // this does not do anything! 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `setModal(false)` at all, because `false` is default value already.

As stated in the Qt [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdialog.html#modal-prop):

> This property holds whether show() should pop up the dialog as modal
>   or modeless.
>
> By default, this property is false and show() pops up the dialog as
>   modeless. Setting his property to true is equivalent to setting
>   QWidget::windowModality to Qt::ApplicationModal.
>
> exec() ignores the value of this property and always pops up the
>   dialog as modal.

So, when you instantiate your `realtimedlg` object your should do this from the heap and just call `show()` method:

```
realtimedlg* dlg = new realtimedlg(this);
dlg->show();
```

You don't need to call `exec()`. Calling of it makes your dialog modal.

Comment: I did that but then my realtimedlg shows for very short time and then disappeared!

Comment: it's because you create it on the stack, your should create from the heap.